# Object variable or With block variable not set - Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have added the reference Microsoft Office 14.0 library to my project. But still this error often comes up.

If i restart MS access it disappears. But again if i re-open the form for execution, it again requires me to add reference and restart.

Some one pls help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying its removed from the references list in your VBA project?  If it is then, there is something very weird going on, are you sure your saving correctly? No read-only flag or security issues?

Comment: Ya.. i tried adding thru Tools - references. But this is not staying. Each time it requires for a restart for me to enter form details

Comment: The title doesn't seem to really match the question body..?

Answer (score 0):

Google for Access Compact and repair. (probably you need a bit more than just the menu command. There is a process where you have to use a commandline to really repair your access db...